# Different validation classes - Angular, bootstrap, HTML

Tags: html, css, angular, bootstrap-4

Why are the validation CSS classes not unified? Angular, bootstrap, HTML

When one validates data in template with the built-in validators, CSS pseudo-classes `:valid` and `:invalid` are used.
When one validates data by angular validators (built-in or custom), CSS classes `.ng-valid` and `.ng-invalid` are used.
When one uses bootstrap for styling, it uses `.is-valid` and `.is-invalid` and `:valid` and `:invalid`.

So, if I have an Angular reactive form with multiple inputs and want to validate all of them and assign the same validation styles from bootstrap, I must assign `[ngClass]` to all of them with checking errors status of the form. And this produces a certain amout of unnecessary code.

Do I really have to do this? Isn't there really an easier way to use what Angular provides?

Comment: I don't see why you would need to use multiple classes, if you create a form using Angular, you can only use the `.ng-valid` class

Comment: You needn't use [ngClass]. Just define in style.css  (or where-ever) `.ng-invalid.ng-touched{...}` and `.ng-valid{...}` Angular add/remove the class for you.

Answer (score 1):

I found my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46810764/angular-4-bootstrap-4-consolidating-validation-classes). The point is in converting value of `valid` property to `.is-valid` or `.is-invalid` class.

I updated it slightly and converted to V10.

```
import { Directive, HostBinding, Self } from '@angular/core';
import { NgControl } from '@angular/forms';

@Directive({
  selector: '[validInvalidClass]'
})
export class ValidInvalidClassDirective {
  @HostBinding('class.is-valid')
  get ngClassValid(): boolean {
    return this.control?.valid ?? false;
  }
  @HostBinding('class.is-invalid')
  get ngClassInvalid(): boolean {
    return this.control?.invalid ?? false;
  }

  public constructor(@Self() private control: NgControl) {}
}
```

May it help anybody else with similar troubles.

Comment: good aproach!! BTW I'll try to "play" with [selector](https://angular.io/api/core/Directive#selector), some like `selector:'.form-control'` apply your directive to all the elements with class "form-control", or some like `selector:'input:not([type="checkbox"])'` to all inputs not checkbox